# Prove $\mathbb{Q}$-subalgebra of quaternions is a division algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

Let D be the $\mathbb{Q}$-subalgebra of $\mathbb{H}$ having basis $1, i, j, k$. Prove that D is a division algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$. This is an exercise from Rotman's Algebra. I only see that is to prove D is a division ring regarded as an algebra over its center $\mathbb{Q}$ by definition. And I know the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ is a 4-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $1, i, j, k$. The hint in the book is: Compute the center $Z(D)$. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: $z\overline{z} \in \Bbb{Q}^*$ whenever $z\ne 0$, you can find the center by looking at $-i z i$ and $-j z j$

Comment: @reuns Thanks! But would you add a few more details? I didn't really follow.

Comment: $z=a+bi+(c+di)j$. Any guess on what is $\overline{z}$? The multiplication is given by $i^2=j^2=-1, ij=-ji$.